# -bash: bower: command not found

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, mean-stack

I am trying to clone this repo https://github.com/jbroquist/bookingappdemo built on mean stack and after doing npm install and npm install -g bower successfully when i do bower install i get this error

```
-bash: bower: command not found
```

When i run the app on the local servers i get these errors in the console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7000/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7000/bower_components/angular/angular.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7000/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7000/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7000/bower_components/angular-motion/dist/angular-motion.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:7000/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined localhost:7000/app.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'factory' of undefined localhost:7000/js/services/config.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined localhost:7000/js/services/authentication.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined localhost:7000/js/services/eventutil.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined localhost:7000/js/services/GoogleCalendarService.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined localhost:7000/js/controllers/MainController.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined localhost:7000/js/directives/InputField.js:1
```

This was the output of running npm install -g bower

```
/usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
bower@1.3.9 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
├── is-root@0.1.0
├── junk@0.3.0
├── stringify-object@0.2.1
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── which@1.0.5
├── osenv@0.1.0
├── opn@0.1.2
├── archy@0.0.2
├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── bower-logger@0.2.2
├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2
├── lru-cache@2.5.0
├── lockfile@0.4.3
├── nopt@3.0.1
├── retry@0.6.1
├── tmp@0.0.23
├── q@1.0.1
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── shell-quote@1.4.2 (array-filter@0.0.1, array-map@0.0.0, array-reduce@0.0.0, jsonify@0.0.0)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.1, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── semver@2.3.2
├── p-throttler@0.0.1 (q@0.9.7)
├── bower-json@0.4.0 (intersect@0.0.3, deep-extend@0.2.11, graceful-fs@2.0.3)
├── promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── fstream@0.1.31 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── fstream-ignore@0.0.6 (inherits@1.0.0, minimatch@0.2.14)
├── tar@0.1.20 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7)
├── glob@4.0.5 (once@1.3.0, inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@1.0.0)
├── bower-config@0.5.2 (osenv@0.0.3, graceful-fs@2.0.3, optimist@0.6.1)
├── decompress-zip@0.0.6 (nopt@2.2.1, mkpath@0.1.0, touch@0.0.2, readable-stream@1.1.13, binary@0.3.0)
├── request@2.36.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, mime@1.2.11, form-data@0.1.4, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@1.0.0, tough-cookie@0.12.1)
├── update-notifier@0.2.0 (semver-diff@0.1.0, string-length@0.1.2, latest-version@0.2.0, configstore@0.3.1)
├── bower-registry-client@0.2.1 (graceful-fs@2.0.3, request-replay@0.2.0, lru-cache@2.3.1, async@0.2.10, mkdirp@0.3.5, request@2.27.0)
├── handlebars@1.3.0 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── mout@0.9.1
├── cardinal@0.4.4 (ansicolors@0.2.1, redeyed@0.4.4)
├── inquirer@0.5.1 (readline2@0.1.0, through@2.3.4, mute-stream@0.0.4, chalk@0.4.0, async@0.8.0, lodash@2.4.1, cli-color@0.3.2)
└── insight@0.4.3 (object-assign@1.0.0, async@0.9.0, lodash.debounce@2.4.1, os-name@1.0.0, tough-cookie@0.12.1, request@2.40.0, configstore@0.3.1, inquirer@0.6.0)
```

Comment: What was the output of `npm install -g bower`?

Comment: I posted the complete output of 'npm install -g bower' in the edited post

Comment: Can you confirm that the output of `echo $PATH` has `/usr/local/bin/` in it?

Comment: Yes it does .This is the output of echo $PATH /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/.rvm/bin

Comment: Actually i did npm install -g bower couple of times and then bower install and it worked and it is not now not giving errors.Thanks for your support